# Connecting to projector in win 8.1 64 bit

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, drivers, asus-laptop, projector

I have Asus X451MA notebook. When I had win 8 projection with my projector worked fine. When I updated to 8.1 (64 bit) I get the message "Your PC Cannot Project to Another screen" when I click <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

What should I do? (all drivers are updated)

Comment: What's your video card, what type of connection (VGA, HDMI, DVI)?

Comment: I am using VGA connection

Comment: Is [this](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X451MA/specifications/) your device? If yes, where is the VGA port?

Comment: It is HDMI, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several folk have had this issue and reinstalling the video driver fixed it. Here is a pretty good look at the problem and solution:  http://wind8apps.com/12033-your-pc-cannot-project-to-another-screen-windows-8-1/

Comment: Can you tell me how can I know which driver should I reinstall? I open Device Menager but I don't know what should I reinstall and what I must install.

Comment: http://www.service.asus.com/#!downloads/c1wax   Search by serial number and download the display  driver

Comment: http://www.service.asus.com/#!downloads/c1wax I don't see "display driver". Help? Model is  Asus X451MA, win 8.1 64 bit

Comment: Sorry, it says VGA not display.

Answer (score -1):

I have same plobrem u don't need to install anything go to control panel -appearnce and personalization-Display-screen resolution - find project to second screen click on that u will find options choose options which suits u and click on it

Any plobrem
Email me at :-chadhasambhav738@gmail.com

Comment: "Choose options which suits you". What options here we are talking about?

Comment: @sambhav OP said it was working before update it means the settings were fine before and please don't add your email